# MySQL: How to get hourly value w.r.t date

Tags: mysql, sql

I was able to do this but I want to narrow down to a certain date only:

```
select count(*) as total, HOUR(crawled_at)
from parsed_products
GROUP by HOUR(crawled_at)
```

How do I mention `crawled_at`'s specific value?

Comment: W.R.T -please don't use acronyms or abbreviations.

Comment: narrow down to a certain date only - what's wrong with a where clause? How do I mention crawled_at's specific value? - I have no idea what this means. Please add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon as you can see it only shows HOURLY data of `crawled_at` column but it does not tell which date the hour belongs to. So I want to pass value to `crawled_at`.

Comment: How can I see that? created_at is clearly a time datatype..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need top use the **where** clause to specify a **filter**, like this

```sql
select count(*) as total, HOUR(crawled_at)
from parsed_products
where crawled_at ='2022-10-18'
GROUP by HOUR(crawled_at)
```

Comment: Thanks, Rohit Bhai. I just added `DATE(crawled_at)` since it was a datetime.